# Barchart/Columnchart - bars with same color on same serie

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I think I already tried everything but I can't solve this problem.

For each company I need to group and show 3 bars with the color of that company and show it annotation for each bar.

**I only can get** something like this:

[image]

But **what I really need** is something like this:
[image]

I already lost more than 1 day searching about this and I already tried everything but I can't find the solution...

This is **my present code**:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  var chart; var data; var options;

  function drawChart() {
    dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Company');
    dataTable.addColumn({ label: 'Total', type: 'number', role: 'style', role: 'annotation' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ label: 'Sales', type: 'number', role: 'style', role: 'annotation' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ label: 'Expenses', type: 'number', role: 'style', role: 'annotation' });

    data.addRow(['Cristal',
                { v: 1400, color: '#b87333', annotation: 'All' },
                { v: 1000, color: '#b87333', annotation: 'S' },
                { v: 400, color: '#b87333', annotation: 'E' }]);

    data.addRow(['Disney',
                { v: 1630, color: '#e5e4e2', annotation: 'All' },
                { v: 1170, color: '#e5e4e2', annotation: 'S' },
                { v: 460, color: '#e5e4e2', annotation: 'E' }]);

    data.addRow(['Skoda',
                { v: 1780, color: '#d5d5e2', annotation: 'All' },
                { v: 660, color: '#d5d5e2', annotation: 'S' },
                { v: 1120, color: '#d5d5e2', annotation: 'E' }]);

    data.addRow(['Yamma',
                { v: 1570, color: '#a80c1b', annotation: 'All' },
                { v: 1030, color: '#a80c1b', annotation: 'S' },
                { v: 540, color: '#a80c1b', annotation: 'E' }]);


    options = {
        legend: 'none'
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ggkep5c6/)

However this is not working... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recommended changes...

1. recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, vs. the older `jsapi`
   according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement (see snippet)

2. two variables are used for the `DataTable`, `data` and `dataTable`
   `data` is never created, probably a typo
   also, when creating the `DataTable`, need to use the `new` keyword

`dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();`

3. finally, both `style` and `annotation` should have their own columns
   see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});


function drawChart() {
  var chart; var dataTable; var options;

  dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Company');
  dataTable.addColumn({label: 'Total', type: 'number'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'style', type: 'string'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'annotation', type: 'string'});

  dataTable.addColumn({label: 'Sales', type: 'number'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'style', type: 'string'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'annotation', type: 'string'});

  dataTable.addColumn({label: 'Expenses', type: 'number'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'style', type: 'string'});
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'annotation', type: 'string'});

  dataTable.addRow(['Cristal',
    {v: 1400}, {v: '#b87333'}, {v: 'All'},
    {v: 1000}, {v: '#b87333'}, {v: 'S'},
    {v:  400}, {v: '#b87333'}, {v: 'E'}
  ]);

  dataTable.addRow(['Disney',
    {v: 1630}, {v: '#e5e4e2'}, {v: 'All'},
    {v: 1170}, {v: '#e5e4e2'}, {v: 'S'},
    {v:  460}, {v: '#e5e4e2'}, {v: 'E'}
  ]);

  dataTable.addRow(['Skoda',
    {v: 1780}, {v: '#d5d5e2'}, {v: 'All'},
    {v:  660}, {v: '#d5d5e2'}, {v: 'S'},
    {v: 1120}, {v: '#d5d5e2'}, {v: 'E'}
  ]);

  dataTable.addRow(['Yamma',
    {v: 1570}, {v: '#a80c1b'}, {v: 'All'},
    {v: 1030}, {v: '#a80c1b'}, {v: 'S'},
    {v:  540}, {v: '#a80c1b'}, {v: 'E'}
  ]);

  options = {
    legend: 'none'
  };

  chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, is right that! Thanks a lot! I didn't know I should use `{v: }` to define the color and the annotation too

Comment: right, and don't even really need object notation, you can supply just the values, similar to the first column...